# How to wait until javascript runs in geckofx c#

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

```
 using (Gecko.AutoJSContext js = new AutoJSContext(geckoWebBrowser1.Window.JSContext))
        {
            js.EvaluateScript(@"
            function send(){
                document.getElementsByClassName('channel-msg-button')[0].click();
                var content =  document.getElementsByClassName('compose-message')[0];
                content.value = '"+message+@"';
                document.getElementsByClassName('yt-dialog-send')[0].click();
                return content.value;
                };
                send();
            ", out outstring);
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

This is not working. It works sometime if the browser is slow or something. But I can't get it to work all the time.

Comment: By the time EvaluateScript returns the javascript should have already run. (as afaik it's a synchronous call) - Purpahs something else is going on.(Like the document isn't ready/finished loading when the EvaluateScript  is called.

Comment: @Tom yes. But i am using document_completed event handler and this javascript is working long time after the document_completed event. I am also using geckobrowser.isAjaxBusy to check if its busy.

Comment: Unfortunately, the document_completed event won't work for this because it's an event to wait for the document to load completely and not to wait for running JS or such. Did you ever figure this out? @NistharKPC